# blackberry field like the OS animated busy clock

Tags: blackberry

Is it possible to use Blackberry's native loading icon(progress bar) from code?[image]

I want to display a progressbar like above when I call a webservice. This progress bar appears when installing an app onto a BlackBerry device.

Comment: Actually you probably don't. If I remember correctly, the OS displays the clock, hour glass, or what ever when the UI event thread stops responding. If your web service call takes more that a few seconds, users seeing the same icon are likely to think the device has frozen and pull the battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the images and resources used in standard BlackBerry applications can be found in "Program Files" of [BlackBerry Theme Studio](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/themes/beta.jsp).

That said, as Richard mentioned, for BlackBerry users this particular clock means "garbage collector is running", which is associated with slowdowns, battery drainage and possible need for re-boot. The hour glass is even worse, it is called "hour glass of doom" or "hour glass of death" and often means re-installing the OS.

I would recommend creating very simple field with paint method showing actual downloading progress. GaugeField might help you here, [see this discussion](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/GaugeField/m-p/172133?query.id=192178) about how to use it.